# How to read in only a subset of polygons from a shapefile in matlab

Tags: matlab, mapping, shapefile

I am trying to read in only a subset of polygons from a shapefile I have.
I am using 'shaperead' to read in the shapefile, but I can't seem to only pull out the polygons I want. I know I should be using the 'selector' pair value arguments, but the exampl online doesn't make sense to me:

```
S = shaperead('concord_roads.shp','Selector',...
       {@(v1,v2) (v1 >= 4) && (v2 >= 200),'CLASS','LENGTH'})
```

There is a 'station number' attribute in my shapefile that identifies each of my polygons. What I want to do is to be able to specify which polygons to map (based on a previous clustering analysis).

Answer (score 1):

```
wanted_stations = [...]; % as previously defined

[S,C] = shaperead(filename,'selector',{@(v1) any(ismember(wanted_stations,v1)) ,'station_number'}); % assuming the attribute name is 'station_number'
```

Basically, for each polygon, shaperead assigns the value of the attribute 'station_number' to v1, then evaluates the anonymous function. The *values* of the wanted_stations vector are incorporated into the function as it is defined.

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked...although I had to include apostrophes and curly braces around the station_number in order for it to be recognised. (ie: wanted_stations=[{'25124'}])...otherwise, the shaperead function just continued to pull down everything.  The inclusion of the curly braces has rendered the data type a cellstring, which is causing problems as I want to automate the process and the station_numbers I have in my vector are of type 'cell', but not'cellstr' (and I can't seem to convert them over). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like the station numbers are stored in the shapefile as strings rather than integers ie '25124' rather than 25124. In that case, if you modify the line to be any(ismember(wanted_stations,str2num(v1))) then you should be able to keep wanted_stations as a numeric vector.